# SaveChanges in Entity Framework insert statement foreign key error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a property object and I wanted to delete that from the latest repository collection. Or I can say detach it before saving to the database. There is a `Property` table which is main and history and detail tables are related to `Property` via a shared `PropertyId` as key. When I am detaching the object from the repository and trying to save it it results in an error.

Doing this.

```
Repository.Detach(P);
```

Errors out on

```
Repository.SaveChanges();
```

Error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_History_Property".
>   The conflict occurred in database "database", table "dbo.Property", column 'PropertyId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete records from other tables that references to the primary key of the record you are trying to delete before deleting the record.

Ex:

**Transaction Table**

```
TransactionID DateOfTransaction CustomerID
1             11/15/11          1
2             11/15/11          2
3             11/15/11          15
4             11/15/11          3
```

**Transaction Detail**

```
TransactionDetailID TransactionID ItemID Quatity
1                   1             43     15
2                   1             32      2
3                   2             43     89
4                   4             32     12
```

`TransactionID` here is a foreign key (Primary Key From other table). Before you could delete the parent record on transaction table you have to delete first all records that references to its PrimaryKey to avoid **FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT ERRORS**

Ex:

If you want to delete transaction 1 from the database, you have to delete transaction details(Transaction Detail 1 and 2) first before you will be allowed to delete transactionID 1

Comment: How can we delete the child object. if i am trying to do that Like P.History and P.Detail then it is null so i can delete that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to use

```
Repository.DeleteObject(P);
```

followed by

```
ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
```

This is of course assuming you are truly using some of the later versions of the EntityFramework that support the DbContext model.

In earlier versions, repository modifications could be made at the Repository level or at the ObjectContext level by doing something like

```
ObjectContext.DeleteObject(P);
```

followed by

```
ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That Causes the same problem but it does not give the foreignkey error. The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted. at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) at

Comment: Deleting it in the repository does not mean it could be properly deleted. You also have to consider foreign key constraints that references to the primary key of the table.